# If condition not working in form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

This is a question from my elder brother's question paper which I'm trying to solve but I am not able to do so .

Create a form containing a two Text fields and radio button and submit button. Name the
text fields account number and amount and radio button as transaction (deposit ,withdraw
and enquiry).Write a JavaScript the validates the text field to have only numbers, the first
text field should be of size 10 and second text field should have values between 500 to
20,000. Using onclick event a jQuery is called that performs necessary transactions and
display the updated value.

.............................................................................

So I have written the following code:

form1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Web Tech DA 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js">
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sub').click(function() {
        var acc=document.getElementById("acc").value;
        var amt=document.getElementById("amt").value;
        var bal=acc%100;//balance , I am using this to dynamically generate a new balance each time a new account number is entered
        
        $("#t1").click(function(){
            bal=acc+amt;
            alert(bal);
        });
        
        $("#t2").click(function(){
        if(acc>amt){
            bal=acc-amt;
            alert(bal);
        }
        else{
            alert('Insufficient Funds.');
        }
        });
        
        $("#t3").click(function(){
        alert(bal);
        });
        
}); 
   
    

});    
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form  name="myform" onsubmit="if(validateform()) {window.alert('succefully submitted')} else {return false;}" >
        
        <p>Account Number : <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="acc" id="acc" height="20px" width="100px" required="required" onblur="validacc(this.value)"></p>
        
        <p>Amount : <input type="text" name="amt" id="amt" height="20px" width="100px" required="required"  onblur="validamt(this.value)"></p>
        
       <p>Transaction : <input type="radio" name="trans" id="t1" value="deposit" />Deposit
                        <input type="radio" name="trans" id="t2" value="withdraw" />Withdraw
                        <input type="radio" name="trans" id="t3" value="enquiry" />Enquiry </p>
        
        <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

main1.css

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    margin: 25px;
}

form p {
    margin: 10px;
}

form input {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

script1.js

```
function validateform() {
var acc = document.getElementById("acc").value.trim();
var amt = document.getElementById("amt").value.trim();

if(validregno(acc)&&validname(amt))
    {window.alert("No errors found");return true;}
else
    {window.alert("invalid entries found");return false;}
}
// Overall Go

function validacc(r)
{
     var p = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{10}$/i);
    if(!p.test(r))
    {
        chngborder("acc");
        return false;
    }
    chngborderr("acc");
    return true;
}
function validamt(amt)
{
     var p = new RegExp( /^[0-9]{1,}$/);
    if(amt>=500 && amt<=20000){
        if(p.test(n))
        {
            chngborderr("amt");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            chngborder("amt");
            return true;
        }
    
    }
    chngborder("amt");
    return false;
}


function chngborder(i)
{
     document.getElementById(i).style.borderColor="red";
}//red color means wrong format
function chngborderr(i)
{
     document.getElementById(i).style.borderColor="green";
}//green color means correct format
```

---

For some reason I'm not able to enter a number in the "Amount" text field and none of the radio buttons are working .

Please point out any mistakes that I have done here .

P.S. I'm new to jQuery and form validation

### UPDATE

I made the changes pointed out and even then for some reason the "Amount" text field doesn't get validated and the "submit" button resets the form .

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and look at the console. There will be plenty of error messages to go through, telling you what mistakes you have made. Once you clean those up, and if you're still having issues, post a new question.

Comment: How do I do that? The dev tools console window only shows me the errors or allows me to edit the code for "this" particular stackoverflow page and not my own code .

Comment: ... open them when you have your page up, not this page. Make changes in your code file, not in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I am analysing your code. if this is exactly what you have, I can notice that
1 - You did not include jQuery library in the  of you.
 you can do it by adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` or `<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>` inside the `<head>` element

2 - I think it is better to add and Else in `onsubmit` event of `#myForm`
       if(validateform()) window.alert('succefully submitted'); else return false.

3 - I have never seen a javascript (.js files) variable declaration starting by `int`: they start with `var` keyword regardless the type of the variable

Comment: I made the changes as u told but it doesn't work even now . Please read the changes I made in the question description

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code.

```
  script1.js

 function validateform() {
 var accValue = document.getElementById("acc").value.trim();
 var amtValue = document.getElementById("amt").value.trim();

 if (validacc(accValue) && validamt(amtValue))
 { window.alert("No errors found"); return true; }
  else
 { window.alert("invalid entries found"); return false; }
}
 // Overall Go

   function validacc(r) {
   var p = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{10}$/i);
  if (!p.test(r)) {
    chngborder("acc");
    return false;
 }
  chngborderr("acc");
 return true;
}
 function validamt(amt) {
 var p = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{1,}$/);
 var amtValue = document.getElementById("amt").value;
 if (amtValue >= 500 && amtValue <= 20000) {
    if (p.test(n)) {
        chngborderr("amt");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        chngborder("amt");
        return true;
    }

}
chngborder("amt");
  return false;
 }


  function chngborder(i) {
  document.getElementById(i).style.borderColor = "red";
  }//red color means wrong format
   function chngborderr(i) {
   document.getElementById(i).style.borderColor = "green";
   }

  //Script inside your html file
            $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sub').click(function() {
            var accValue = document.getElementById("acc").value;
            var amtValue = document.getElementById("amt").value;
            var bal = accd % 100;})

    $("#t1").click(function(){
        bal = Number(document.getElementById("aac").value) +   
    Number(document.getElementById("amt").value);
        alert(bal);
    });

    $("#t2").click(function(){
    if(acc > amt){
        Number(document.getElementById("aac").value) +
    Number(document.getElementById("amt").value);
        alert(bal);
    }
    else{
        alert('Insufficient Funds.');
    }
    });


   });
```

Comment: Do not forget to add jquery library in the <head> section.